# How to permanently cache Next.js images on build time?

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

My image URLs expire hourly, I want to cache images permanently on build time. Is this possible?

I went through cache behavior docs, not sure I understand how it works.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#caching-behavior

Comment: `next/image` optimizes images dynamically (and caches them) upon request, you can't cache them at build time.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution already?